# A very strange continuous stochastic process: can we build one ? Does it exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, covariance

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $X_t:\Omega \times \mathbb [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a continuous stochastic process with the following property:

There exists an $n>1$ such that for any real sequence $0<s_1<\ldots<s_n<t<T$, denoting $\mathbb X=(X_{s_1},\ldots, X_{s_n})$ and $\mathbb A_i= Cov[X_{s_i},\mathbb X]$, we have $Cov[X_{t},\mathbb X]= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i \mathbb A_i$ for some real coefficients $a_i \neq 0 $ for all $i=1,\ldots, n$, and if we remove any term from $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i \mathbb A_i$, then the equation has no solutions anymore.

Does such stochastic process exist ? If so, can you give an example ? If not, why ?

For $n=1$, the Brownian bridge has this property. I would be very happy to find such a process for $n=2$, and over the moon if we can build such a process for any $n$.

EDIT: In the case of Brownian bridge (so $n=1$), we have (writing $s_1$ as $s$)

$Cov[X_{t},\mathbb X]=Cov[X_{t},X_s]$ and $\mathbb A_1= Cov[X_{s}, X_s]$. We get

$$Cov[X_{t},\mathbb X]= \frac{T-t}{T-s} \mathbb A_1$$

so $a_1=\frac{T-t}{T-s}$ which is never $0$.

Comment: In what point is this process strange?

Comment: The fact that the covariance vector above can always be written as a linear combination  of the other covariance vectors. Can you think of one ?

Comment: Which version of "continuous stochastic process" do you mean?  Wikipedia lists several kinds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stochastic_process

Comment: Almost all sample paths are continuous, like Brownian motion for example.

Comment: @W.Volante I am slightly struggling with all the notation. It could help if you explain how the Brownian bridge (constrained Brownian motion to be $0$ at time $1$) satisfies this condition. We have $cov(B(s),B(t)) = s(1-t)$ for $s<t$. What are the $a_i$ in this case? If I had to answer your question for now, I'd be quite confident of the existence of such a process, so confident I'd say it was linked to the Brownian bridge. But all that on the side till this is clarified.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I added the Brownian bridge example

Comment: @W.Volante thank  you and +1